# How to Change innerHTML on Interval pulling from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, setinterval

Trying to get an element to change every x number of seconds. When I click the button it should change the innerHTML, looping through an array. The code below changes the text but displays the last result in the array.

```
<h1 id="header">Agent</h1>
<button id="change-header" onclick="loopHeader()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function loopHeader() {
  var loopHeader = setInterval(changeText, 1000);
}

function changeText() {
  var headers = ["Agent", "Expert", "Homes", "Service", "Results"];
  var text = "";
  var i = 0;
  var x = document.getElementById("header");
  for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    text = headers[i];
    x.innerHTML = text;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your ID is `id="change-header"` but you're calling `document.getElementById("header");`

Comment: Updated, referring to `<h1 id="header">Agent</h1>`

Comment: @j08691 that's the button id :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the count outside of the function, and then keep looping round and resetting to 0 when at end.

```js
function loopHeader() {
  var loopHeader = setInterval(changeText, 1000);
}

var headers = ["Agent", "Expert", "Homes", "Service", "Results"];
var loopItem = 0;

function changeText() {
  loopItem++;
  if (loopItem == headers.length) {
    loopItem = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = headers[loopItem];
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="header">
  
 </div>
<button id="change-header" onclick="loopHeader()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because every time you `changeText` is called it start changing the `innerHTML` of the button by the text from the array all from index 0 to the end (It's happening you just can't see it because it's happening fast). What you need is to define `i` outside the function and every time the function is called increment `i` and show its corresponding value from the array without a loop. Like this:

```html
<button id="change-header" onclick="loopHeader()">Click Me</button>

<script>
  function loopHeader() {
    // if you want to start the animation just after the button is clicked, then uncomment the next line
    // changeText();
    var loopHeader = setInterval(changeText, 1000);
  }

  var i = 0; // i declared outside with the initiale value of 0
  var headers = ["Agent", "Expert", "Homes", "Service", "Results"]; // this also should be outside (what's the point of redefining it every time the function is called)
  function changeText() {
    var x = document.getElementById("change-header"); // the id is change-header
    // increment i and check if its beyond the boundaries of the loop, or just use modulo operator t prevent it from going beyond
    i = (i + 1) % headers.length;
    x.textContent = headers[i]; // textContent is better than innerHTML
  }
</script>
```